# American and European date/time formats in Access Database conversion

Tags: sql, date, datetime, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Im currently working to get a text file from a call log into access.
However there are a few problems:

- 2 tabels are mixed within the text file
- the dates and times are in American Standard while we use European Standard here.

What I have done:

- imported the txt file, all as text with a "," as the point to start a new entity.
- split the 2 tables and referenced them to eachother.

Now I only need to change the date + time, how it is in the database (as text):

11/18/2013 10:28:29 AM

This is the 18th of the 11th month
When changing the format from text to date it automaticly uses my European settings from my pc to identify the date, I tried to format it as an american date, european date and setting my pc to american. the only time access saw the correct dates if I set my pc to american. 
Other times it would try to read everything as european, all days under the 12th of the month will be seen as months. I cant keep my pc on american settings because of the other parts of the database.

Is there a normal solution for this?
currently im trying to split the day, month and year from the entity.

12/6/2013 3:01:42 PM

1/8/2014 9:34:29 AM

But as you can see the dates do not have a set length so using the left function is giving me problems.
If anybody can help me with a solution for the conversion or help me split the date and month it would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with a UDF:

```
 UPDATE aTable
 SET aTable.Newdate = BuildDate(aTable.DateString)
```

Then the code for the UDF

```
Function BuildDate(sDate)
    If Not IsNull(sDate) Then
        asdate = Split(sDate, "/")
        BuildDate = CDate(asdate(1) & "/" & asdate(0) & "/" & asdate(2))
    End If
End Function
```